# Does VS Code has any shortcut like ctrl+q in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-code, shortcut

Does VS Code (I currently use v1.8.1) has any shortcut like ctrl+q in eclipse?

It returns your cursor to the place where you stopped writing code(very useful for fast code browsing)

and it is different to alt+left which navigate backward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** I have found that [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sadesyllas.edit-locations-history) extension should do that you're asking. I suggest trying it out.

**Original:**

Out of the box in VS Code, this command does not exist. The list of default shortcuts can be found [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/keybindings), or you can open the keybindings settings in VS Code (ctrl+k, ctrl+s on Windows) and see which commands are available.

If you'd like to suggest this as a feature, you can open a new issue on [GitHub](https://www.github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new) or consider creating an extension.

If I understand correctly, you want a command that will move the cursor to where the last edit in a document was made.

This should be possible using an extension that listens to document change events and records the position of the cursor. Then, when the command is issued, it sets the editors cursor to that saved position.

Comment: thanks Llewey,  the extension do provided the feature as I want, but it seems not run very well, due to sometimes it goto a wrong place (just jump to the head of one of my openning file), and I found an alternative extension and the shurtcut is supported.

Comment: could you share the extension that you are using so others can benefit as well?

Comment: it is goto-last-edit-location by Christian Oetterli, the extension url is [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=krizzdewizz.goto-last-edit-location)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try "Eclipse Keymap" from Alphabot Security, has a lot of eclipse bindings.

Comment: but it does not provide this short cut, anyway, the third-party plugin does it perfectly for me

Comment: which third party you are speaking of?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a built-in way to do this, but you could work around it by using an extension such as https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alefragnani.Bookmarks .